# Android Studio issue when installing

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, system

I'm not sure if this is at the right area, please tell me if not. When I try to run the android studio installer after downloading it, it says that "Installer integrity check has failed".

[image: error image]

I really want to move from eclipse to Android Studio, But I can't figure this out. Can someone help me?

Comment: The download may be corrupt.  Have you tried re-downloading the installer?

Comment: First thing I did, downloaded again as soon as the error came up.

Comment: Just got it to work by downloading the .rar version instead of the .exe. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you feel an answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps the community by reducing the number of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are reaching this page from an error message, you are having a problem installing a program. The downloaded file is either incomplete or modified from the original file.

Here is the issue reported about the same problem:

Issue 185624: Android studio Installer NSIS Error
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185624

Comment: Just got it to work by downloading the .rar version instead of the .exe. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to know that it works for you. Can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is that your download of the android studio is corrupt, which easily can happen if you're using a download accelerator. One solution would be to use NCRC switch.

you can do this by

1. Drag and drop exe file command prompt. Now it should look something like this
       **D:\android-studio-bundle-143.3101438-windows.exe**
2. Now make it 
   **D:\android-studio-bundle-143.3101438-windows.exe /NCRC** and hit enter.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Android programming specially with Android Studio is very bad experience for me.

Comment: It works  for me (with PowerShell). If drag and drop doesn't work on command prompt (cmd),  and you are lazy to type, use PowerShell.

Comment: yes, the exe installer was corrupted. I got it downloaded again