# Android Studio installation error in windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio

> Error : - (NSIS Error) Installer integrity check has failed.

Tried solutions :

- 1) Set java path.
- 2) Run Android Studio as an Administrator.
- 3) Again downloaded Android Studio and tried to install.

Please let me know if anyone having these type of problem or have any solution for that.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio issue when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937982/android-studio-issue-when-installing)

Comment: you can download .zip instead of .exe from the same page you downloaded but further down.

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna didn't worked for me.